# How to obtain values from Serializer (CsvEncoder) by index instead of by name of field?

Tags: symfony

Is there a way to obtain values from Serializer (CsvEncoder) by index instead of by name of field ?

By example :

```
$serializer = new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()], [new CsvEncoder($delimiter = "\t", $enclosure = '"')]);
$csvFile = __DIR__ . '/../../uploads/' . 'test.txt';
$csvContents=file_get_contents($csvFile);
$datas = $serializer->decode($csvContents, 'csv');

foreach($datas as $data) {
            $idCli = $data['C1 Numéro/client'];
}
```

Is there a way to use $data[0] instead of $data['C1 Numéro/client'];

Comment: What's the format of the test.txt ? Maybe it's not the best solution but you could use 'array_keys($datas)', and it will do the trick